# Suppose $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are real numbers, $0 \lt a \lt b $, and $d \gt 0$. Prove that if $ac \ge bd$ then $c \gt d$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

**Background:** I'm currently working through the book ["How To Prove It" by Daniel J. Velleman](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/sXt-ROLLNHcC?hl=en) when I came across a problem in the simple proofs chapter I think I solved, but have no one to check over my proof. Here's the question:

**Question :** Suppose $a,b,c,$ and $d$ are real numbers, $0 \lt a \lt b $, and $d \gt 0$. Prove that if $ac \ge bd$ then $c \gt d$

**My Approach :** Proof by Contrapositive

So I decided to list my hypotheses:

1. $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $0 \lt a \lt b$
3. $d \gt 0$
4. $ac \ge bd$

and my conclusion:

1. $c \gt d$

After this I decided to attempt to prove the contrapositive so I wrote
$$\lnot (c \gt d) \rightarrow \lnot(\text{Hypothesis})$$
$$d \ge c \rightarrow \lnot(\text{Hypothesis})$$

So then I worked out that $d \ge c$ and $b \gt a$ so I multiplied each of them by a,b, and c separately to get two that fit together:
$$bd \ge bc $$
$$bc \gt ac $$
to make this:
$$ bd \ge bc \gt ac \implies bd \gt ac$$
which is true if $d \ge c$
$$d \ge c \rightarrow bd\gt ac$$
$$\therefore \lnot (c \gt d) \rightarrow \lnot(ac \ge bd)$$
$$\therefore ac \ge bd \rightarrow c \gt d$$

While I reached the same answer as the book, it does not match the proof in the book so I don't know if I am wrong or correct and I don't want to be building proof writing habits that are incorrect. Thank you

Comment: I'm dubious about your assertion that $bc>ac$. I can see this will be true if $c>0$, but that is not one of your hypotheses.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I got $c \gt 0$ from $ac \ge bd$ because for that to be true and both a and b be positive, shouldn't c have to be greater than 0?

Comment: @Nragis The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @Nragis Your third inequality $bd > ad$ is the same as the first inequality. Was this supposed to be something else?

Comment: @Nragis -- I think the chain $bd>bc>ac$ should be $bd\geq bc>ac$ . But the consequent is the same, $bd>ac$ .

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire I just fixed it, idk what happened when translating from my paper onto the forum, but now it should make sense

Comment: @Nragis Your proof is fine after the adjustment is made that was alluded to in the above comments. I took the liberty of updating your post accordingly. 

Now what you should do is make the proof nice; there is no need, for example, for the last three logical equivalences.

Begin your proof by saying something like, "Suppose $0 < a < b$ and $d > 0$. We will proceed with proof by contrapositive. Assume that $c \leq d$. Since $ac \geq bd > 0$ and $0 < a < b$ we know $c>0$. Therefore, $bd \geq bc$. Also $bc > ac$, so we have $bd > ac$, as desired." Something like that...maybe shorter.

Comment: @Nragis However, you should attempt a direct proof. A direct proof is always desirable to have, and you should try to construct one if time permits.

Comment: @Nragis A direct proof can be obtained using a similar strategy that you used in your proof; namely, using the transition property of inequalities $a < b$ and $b < c$ imply $a < c$. 

Hint: Multiply $0 < a < b$ by $d$. Look for a connection with the assumption $bd \leq ac$. Cancel the $a$'s since $a \neq 0$. State the conclusion.

Comment: Well I already read one of the answers to the question, which contains a direct proof so I'll move onto the next exercise and attempt to solve that one without any bobbles

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire is a proof by contrapositive the same thing as a proof by contradiction? I was just thinking about the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is a irrational number and they said that was a proof by contradiction and it seemed just like a contrapositive.

Comment: @Nragis Those two methods are different. If you have an implication $p\imples q$, then the proposition is $~q \implies ~p$ is logically equivalent to the original implication. So for proof by contrapositive, we assume $~q$ is true and then deduce the truth of $~p$. Proof by contradiction, on the other hand, proceeds by assuming that $p$ is true, but $q$ is false, and if $q$ is false, then $~q$ is true. Using the truths of $p$ and $~q$, we then need to derive a contradiction.

Comment: @Nragis Similarly if we want to prove that a single proposition is true, like $\sqrt{2}$, you assume that it is false, that is, $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, and then seduce a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show you a fairly simple, direct way to prove this, and also how it could be written up.

By assumption, we have $a < b$ and $d > 0$. Multiplying our inequality by $d$, we obtain $ad < bd$. If, in addition, $bd \leq ac$, then $$ad < bd \leq ac,$$ hence $$ad < ac.$$ Dividing by $a$ gives us $d < c$, as desired.

(William Elliot's proposed proof is even simpler!)

The contrapositive is most often useful when your original statement is unwieldy, but the conclusion seems more manageable. Using the contrapositive here doesn't help much. For an example of when the contrapositive *is* useful, try proving this: If $n^2$ is odd, then $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks! The book said to use a contrapositive in the hint so I blindly followed it without checking for a much simpler method such as this one.

Comment: Not a wasted effort! It's good to try the contrapositive, and excellent practice to prove things more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0 < a < b$. $c \geq bd/a > 1×d = d$ follows from $ac \geq bd.$
Your proof is excessively complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now, because $\frac{b}{a}$ is always greater than 1. Thanks, was trying to be fancy and use new techniques I'd learned and completely overlooked the obvious I guess

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes I do, first day learning set theory and my big lesson is perfect notation is everything. and check everything a million times